# hive external table incremental load

Tags: hive, sqoop

Please see my process & issue below:
step1 -I want to load one mysql table data in a incremental fashion.So first I am using SQOOP to import incremental data using
'INCREMENTAL append check-column  last-value'
assume this stores into HDFS folder '/sqoopdir1'
step 2 - I want to use a pig script to do some data validations like duplicate checking and the result should go to '/user/root/pigdir'
step 3 - I want to create a hive external table 'extsample' pointing to pig output directory as "stored as textfile location '/user/root/pigdir'

My issue here is 
(1)SQOOP will create part-m-00001,part-m-00002 etc in folder /sqoopdir1 in HDFS.But for each incremental process, I just need latest file for PIG process to pick automatically.
(2) Another issue issue is, PIG creates part-r-00000 file in /user/root/pigdir. Second time job fails saying file already exists, so I have to rename the file to run the PIG job.

In short I want to have initial loaded data + just inserted/updated records in final hive table.As I am a beginner, could you please help to resolve the issues mentioned or advise a better approach.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) As per my understanding you are trying to sqoop each incremental data into same folder? But that cant be true, sqoop will also throw an exception folder already exists.  Part-m-00 files are output of sqoop so if you think about it all those "part" files are your incremental data generated by single sqoop ingestion.

We need to handle this in the code, like for each sqoop incremental ingestion we need to provide a dynamic output location (append timestamp to folder name)... Same goes with Pig. If you are using shell script to call sqoop and pig passing a dynamic location is very easy.

Comment: Hi,since it is SQOOP incremental APPEND, it is allowing me to have multiple files like part-m-00001,part-m-00002 etc in same folder

Comment: Then you might need a staging folder to hold one particular incremental data and try to pass it to Pig script.Or use a timestamp based logic to get the latest incremental file and feed it to the Pig script...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Do you agree that using pig scripts in between is a valid approach ? If so could you please give me some valid data validation examples(like duplicate removal) using pig ? Also should the staging table be external table housing just a particular days incremental data ?Do we need to perform any operations on staging table data or that is used just to house incremental data?